# Rails5.2 - Active Record .select() causing error when .count is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

How do I add another column to scope and still be able to call .count, .find, .where, etc.

```
 User.all.select('users.*,"one" as one').count
```

Result:

```
  (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(users.*,"one" as one) FROM "users"
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):7
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as")
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(users.*,"one" as one) FROM "users"
                                   ^
: SELECT COUNT(users.*,"one" as one) FROM "users"
```

Comment: what you are trying to count ??

Comment: This is a simplified example, but need to count a scope after much manipulation, added `select as` statements and unions.

Comment: Can you try writing it as `User.all.select("users.*, 'one' as one").count`? (swap double quotes and single quotes). In PostgreSQL you need to use single quotes for strings.

Comment: @GregoryWitek That gives the same error

Comment: `User.all.select("users.*, 'one' as one").size`  works, but might not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 User.all.select('users.*,"one" as one').count(:all)
```

and

```
 User.all.select('users.*,"one" as one').count(:id)
```

Both work because it specifies what the SQL code should count on.

Comment: They don't produce the query the op is looking for though.

Comment: Look at the query the op provided, the generated sql of your queries doesn't use the `select` fields

Comment: If you are returning a count, the select does not matter, but matters, if you do other operations before the count.